# Is there a way to display two android buttons at opposite ends of the screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to get my two buttons to display on opposite ends of the screen.

Here's my XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previous_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish (The bottom arrow buttons are what I'm trying to modify) But they keep crowding together on the left or the center. (The above code puts them in the center. I want one to the left and one to the right.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change LinearLayout to FrameLayout and FrameLayout's width to match_parent

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">


    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/previous_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/next_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />


  </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would nest a constraint layout inside that frameLayout(I'm assuming this is for some sort of a fragment and you need to pass the frame layout) and then you could simply do it by

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previous_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
 />
```

the other button something like that

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" 
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" 

/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty view and set `layout_weight` like below:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation=horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previous_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />

        <View
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLeftArrow"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivRightArrow"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"/>
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivRightArrow"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivLeftArrow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```